# Preventing Simultaneous ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a voting script, and it works fine when i vote one at a time, but when i vote on many items as fast as i can, some malfunction and stop, what can I do to prevent this? I only wanted to have one process at a time and wait for the process to finish before making another one.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'vote/now',
            timeout: 15000,
            context: this,
            data: {
                'postid': $(this).attr('data-id'),
                'vote': value,
                'token': current_token
            },
            success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
                $points.fadeOut(500,function(){
                    $points.html(data);
                    $points.fadeIn(500);
                });
            },
            error: function(){
                $points.fadeOut(500,function(){
                    $points.html("Sorry, Try again");
                    $this.find('button').removeClass('clicked').attr('disabled',false);
                    $points.removeClass('busy');
                    $points.fadeIn(500);
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: why not disable all your buttons with jquery before the request and then enable them again after the request?

Answer (score 3):

A common idiom (not just Javascript, but any language) for serializing network requests is to put arguments into a queue or a stack and then send one at a time.

Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
var argumentStack = [];
var isSending = false;

function serialSend(data) {
  argumentStack.push(data);
  trySend();
}

function trySend() {
  if(!isSending && argumentStack.length > 0) {
        var data = argumentStack.pop();

        isSending = true;

        $.ajax(data, success, error);
        // in success and error handlers do this:
        //    isSending = false;
        //    setTimeout(trySend, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: i like the idea of using booleans.

Comment: could you explain what .push() and .pop() is doing?

Comment: `.push` is adding element to array, `.pop` removes last element and returns it.

Comment: i just disabled the buttons and reenabled them instead. The comment of my question was what I did.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe inside the function the first line should be to deactivate the button or link that is calling the function and the the last line to activate it back. That way it would be impossible to call the function while it is still running...

Answer (score 1):

Disable or hide the vote button as soon as it's clicked. Then, in the success and error functions of your AJAX request, enable or show it again.

Looks like you already do something like it in the error function.

Answer (score 1):

you can show a `loading` or `spinning` image over the body to avoid next ajax call.

```
$.ajaxStart(function() {
    $("img#loading").show();
});

$.ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("img#loading").hide();
});
```